# Use regex to separate a cityname and optional countrycode (ISO-3166) into groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

As input, I have a list of citynames:

```
Frankfurt an der Oder
Hamburg
Baden-Baden
Wickede (Ruhr)
Jokne’am
```

I assume that any combination of whitespace and special characters is possible.
SOME of these will have a ISO-3166-2 or ISO-3166-3 countrycode added in brackets:

```
Frankfurt an der Oder
Saint-Sulpice (FR)
Hamburg
Erlenbach-Zürich (CH)
Baden-Baden
Ra’s al-Chaima (ARE)
Wickede (Ruhr)
Jokne’am
Hobbiton (W-Farthing) (ME)
```

Again, i assume that any combination of whitespace and special characters is possible for a cityname.
What I know is that IF there is a countrycode, it will always be at the end of the string, it will always be 2 or 3 uppercase [A-Z]. So (ARE) is a countrycode, (UK) is,  (Ruhr) is not, (Abc) isn't either.

What I came up with is this:

```
^(.*)(?:\()([A-Z]{2,3})(?:\))$
```

One group to catch all the possible characters of the cityname `(.*)`, followed by a non-capturing group containing the opening bracket character `(?:\()`, one group to catch 2 or 3 upper case word characters `([A-Z]{2,3})` and finally one non-captunring group to get the closing bracket character `(?:\))`.

This works really well for citynames that have a countrycode suffix. `group(1)` will have the cityname and `group(2)` the countrycode without brackets.

But what I need for citynames without a countrycode would be `group(1)` = cityname and `group(2)` = null.
I tried to make the second part optional by putting it all in one big group and ?'ing it, but that does not work:

```
(.*)((?:\()([A-Z]{2,3})(?:\)))?
```

Comment: Use `^(.*?)(?:\s*\(([A-Z]{2,3})\))?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/QwgtED/1))

Comment: A bit longer but faster `^\h*(\S+(?:\h+\S+)*?)(?:\h*\(([A-Z]{2,3})\))?$`